# Soma de campos de tabela com PHP e Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Preciso somar alguns campos de uma tabela. Tenho o id da transação e preciso somar todos os campos `amount` com o id 224, todos com 222.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa somar todos os `amount` que tem o mesmo `customer_id`?

Comment: Sim, creio que seria mais ou menos como a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando apenas um select no banco de dados, facilitando a sua vida. No seu caso o select ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
select sum(amount) as 'amount' from `tb_customer_credit` where customer_id = 224
```

Referente a linha de código acima, você só precisara substituir o valor 224 pelo nome da variável que será utilizada pela sua aplicação para enviar o ID.

Você também conseguiria pegar o maior valor, entre outras coisas utilizando apenas o select, diminuindo assim a quantidade de coisas no php e diminuindo o tempo de resposta do seu site.

Comment: Para fazer no Code Igniter, você deve criar uma nova função na sua classe Model (aonde faz os selects no BD) e colar lá esse código.

Comment: Perfeito, tive que apenas trocar o 224 pela id que estou puxando e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso usando a função `SUM` e agrupando os registros pelo campo que você quer com `GROUP BY`. Exemplo:

```
SELECT `customer_id`,  SUM(`amount`) AS `amount` 
FROM `tb_customer_credit` 
GROUP BY `customer_id`;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30c6bb/3)**

Assim terá a soma de todos os registros. Caso precise da soma de apenas um registro, pode fazer da forma que o @BernardoKowacic fez, utilizando o `WHERE`.

Comment: Seria apenas 1 mesmo, consegui fazer com o código do @BernardoKowacic, esse id eu pego do cookie do usuario.